# vsftp encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, tls, ftp

I want to configure VSFTP for ftps protocol and it has some choices to select the encryption type: tlsv1, sslv2, sslv3.
I read that tls version 1 has some security issues but in the man page it says that tls v1 is preferred. my question is why tls v1 is preferred and is it more secure to use ssl v3?

Answer (score 1):

The details of the differences were explained well on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/179139/1404)

But the summary is this: TLSv1 is the successor to SSLv3. It was based on SSLv3 and includes several updates to the ciphers and key exchange. It also handles renegotiation extensions better.

TLSv1.0 could be considered SSLv3.1, and even appears to be identified that way in the handshake methods.